# Error when try to instantiate chain code on Hyperledger channel on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have set up a blockchain network using Bluemix services. When I try to instantiate the deployed .bna file on my channel I get the following error:

Error: /opt/go/src/ibm-bcs-b05c71a3dc784daebd6dc064d552a7ac-test1-1.0 (from $GOROOT) /chaincode/input/src/ibm-bcs-b05c71a3dc784daebd6dc064d552a7ac-test1-1.0 (from $GOPATH) /opt/gopath/src/ibm-bcs-b05c71a3dc784daebd6dc064d552a7ac-test1-1.0 "

Can someone help me please?

Comment: How did you deploy the bna to bluemix and what actions had you taken to get this error

Comment: I have deployed it usin Bluemix web UI. I get tis error when choose "instantiate" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A business network archive (bna) doesn't contain any chaincode, it is only the definition and implementation of that business network, so you cannot deploy a bna file and try to instantiate it through the ibm blockchain platform UI. In order to deploy a business network to the platform you need to follow this guide
https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/platform-deployment/

Comment: i am not convinced this is correct, a bna contains chaincode writen in node. The code under logic.js is exactly that, it interacts with the registries and allows the ledger to be updated. that is chaincode. Plus the ibm cloud allows you to specify what type your chaincode is ( Go or Node ) when trying to instantiate it.

Comment: i am still not convinced. the UI clearly supports it, you can instantiate a network at that point it doesn't matter it was installed via a bna or something else. Everything supports this and I am actually fairly certain that behind the scenes, the UI does call network start. I actually have an open question on this right now, this is how I found this answer.

Comment: look, this is hardly the best way to have a discussion on this subject, the point is the UI can do what you say it can't. I know because I've already seen it happening and can prove it as well. I am 100% sure the UI can instantiate the chaincode even if it comes from a bna. All I need to figure out is the arguments issue which is what I described in my open question.